# Python: how to wait for process return code using subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using `subprocess.call` to start my exe file with arguments this way:

```
def run_file(self, file_path):
    subprocess.call([r'c:\file.exe', self.server_ip_address, file_path])
```

This works fine but now i want to wait to my `return code`.

So i try to use this approach:

```
def run_file(self, file_path):
    process = subprocess.call([r'c:\file.exe', self.server_ip_address, file_path])
    process.wait()
    print(process.returncode)
```

And got this `error`:

> ```
> process.wait() AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'wait'
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call).

Answer (score 0):

Use `subprocess.run` instead of `subprocess.call`. It is blocking so no need for `wait`.
https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: I have replaced subprocess.call with subprocess.run and remove the process.wait(), also i added to subprocess.run function check=True and still this is not wait